# Nuxt 3 folder structure for API call functions

Tags: rest, directory, nuxtjs3

I am building a Nuxt 3 app, I am doing only the frontend part. I created .env file and added my base URL, created a composable

```
export const useApiFetch: typeof useFetch = (request, opts?) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const defaultHeaders = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  };

  return useFetch(request, {
    headers: defaultHeaders,
    baseURL: config.public.baseURL,
    ...opts,
  });
};
```

And I have couple of functions that I am doing only API calls to the server:
similar to the function below.

```
const subscribeBeta = async (email: string) => {
    const response = await useApiFetch("endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
      body: { email },
    });
    return response;
  };
```

I want to keep similar functions in the same folder and use them in the different components,
What is the best folder structure to store my functions to do API calls?
In React there is an API folder but I don't know about Nuxt 3.

I put them in composables, and also put them in utils folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (2023-07-16)**:

The implementation described in the original response presents a problem of **duplication of API calls**. To fix this, it is necessary to wrap the call method with the `useAsyncData` composable in the repository classes and adjust how the api plugin is consumed on pages and components (basically use the return type of the `useAsyncData` composable).

To make it easier I set up [this repository](https://github.com/luizzappa/nuxt3-repository-pattern) with these modifications, plus it uses the `ofetch` library (the one Nuxt 3 uses behind the scene) instead of `ohmyfetch`.

If you are interested in a more detailed explanation see [this article](https://medium.com/@luizzappa/nuxt-3-repository-pattern-organising-and-managing-your-calls-to-apis-with-typescript-acd563a4e046) I wrote commenting on the implementation of the repository code mentioned above.

---

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**:

Take a look at: https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/api-management-in-nuxt-3-with-typescript/

In case the link no longer works, I copy the main parts of the design pattern below:

The article uses the `repository pattern`, which serves as an intermediary between the datasource and the business logic.

Create a folder called `repository` and the following files inside it:

**File: repository/factory.ts** : `HttpFactory` is an encapsulation that accepts an HTTP client.

```
import { $Fetch } from 'ohmyfetch';

class HttpFactory {
  private $fetch: $Fetch;

  constructor(fetcher: $Fetch) {
    this.$fetch = fetcher;
  }

  /** 
    * method - GET, POST, PUT
    * URL
  **/
  async call<T>(method: string, url: string, data?: object, extras = {}): Promise<T> {
    const $res: T = await this.$fetch(url, { method, body: data, ...extras });
    return $res;
  }
}

export default HttpFactory;
```

**File: repository/modules/auth.ts**: this will act as a repository for all things authentication, including creating a user account, logging in a user, resetting a user’s password, and so on.

```
import HttpFactory from './factory';
import { ICreateAccountInput, ICreateAccountResponse, ILoginInput, ILoginResponse } from 'types';

class AuthModule extends HttpFactory {
  private RESOURCE = '/auth';

  async login(credentials: ILoginInput): Promise<ILoginResponse> {
    return await this.call<ILoginResponse>('POST', `${this.RESOURCE}/login`, credentials);
  }

  async create(account: ICreateAccountInput): Promise<ICreateAccountResponse> {
    return await this.call<ICreateAccountResponse>('POST', `${this.RESOURCE}/register`, account);
  }
}

export default AuthModule;
```

Then we create a plugin so that we can access it from within a component.

**File: plugins/api.ts**

```
import { $fetch,FetchOptions } from 'ohmyfetch';
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import AuthModule from '~~/repository/modules/auth';

/** ApiInstance interface provides us with good typing */
interface IApiInstance {
  auth: AuthModule
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  
  const fetchOptions: FetchOptions = {
    baseURL: nuxtApp.$config.API_BASE_URL,
  }

  /** create a new instance of $fetcher with custom option */
  const apiFetcher = $fetch.create(fetchOptions);

  /** an object containing all repositories we need to expose */
  const modules: IApiInstance = {
    auth: new AuthModule(apiFetcher),
  };

  return {
    provide: {
      api: modules,
    },
  };
});
```

Example of use:
**File: pages/login.vue**

```
// ...
// ...
const { $api } = useNuxtApp();

const form = reactive<ILoginInput>({
  email: '',
  password: '',
});

async function handleSubmit(): void {

  try {
        const credentials: ILoginInput = {
          email: form.email,
          password: form.password,
        };
  
        const response = await $api.auth.login(credentials);
        console.log(response)
        // allow user access into the app
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

}
```

Comment: This example uses `ohmyfetch` which is extraordinary replacement for standard (recommended) Nuxt 3 `useFetch`. So it's quite outdated. The main problem of this sample is that the author did not even bother to check his code before posting. It's a shame. So far there is no working and comprehensive example of Repository API Pattern for Vue3 / Nuxt 3 on the internet yet.

Comment: @mr.boris It's a small mistake the author made.. I fixed it in my comment. And because it's a repository pattern, just change `ohmyfetch` to `ofetch`, that's the advantage of using this pattern. I found the post very helpful and it gave me some guidance. The big problem with this solution is that if you use SSR and call the API on the backend, it will be requested twice. For that, just use `useAsyncData` wrapping `$fetch`. This weekend I will have some time and write an article and a repository with this solution

Comment: I have updated my original response

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is:

- stateful logic into `/composables`
- stateless functions into `/utils`

AFAIK there is no other dedicated folder with auto-imports on client side meant for reusable functions.

**Option number 1** You can create a sub-directory inside either of the dirs to keep your files with API calls organized. Then you just have to deal with the fact [Nuxt is not scanning `/composables` and `/utils` recursively by default](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/composables#how-files-are-scanned). But it is easy to adapt.

**Option number 2** You may consider [using `/server` folder](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server) and delegate the actual external API calls to Nuxt server part. Then from your client components you can just `useFetch` respective server routes. Might be useful to separate concerns inside your app. But if you only need plain API calls with little to no extra processing, then it is probably an overengineering.